# Remove last comma from a bash for loop generated string

Tags: bash, sed, for, here-document

I am dealing with a situation where I need to create a comma separated list from an array into a heredoc and remove the last comma. I am using bash `for` piped into `sed` which is erasing all commas instead of the last one. A simplified example is as follows:

```
x=$(for i in a b c; do echo "${i}",; done| sed 's/,$//')
echo $x
a b c
```

Desired output:

```
a, b, c
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that, by default,  `echo` adds a new line each time it is called and `sed` was operating on those new lines.  You couldn't see that because, when bash processes `$(...)`, those new lines are converted to spaces.  So, to fix the problem while making the smallest change to your approach:

```
$ x=$(for i in a b c; do echo -n "${i}",; done| sed 's/,$//') ; echo $x
a,b,c
```

The option `-n` tells `echo` not to add new lines.

If you want spaces between the items, they are easily added:

```
$ x=$(for i in a b c; do echo -n "${i}, " ; done| sed 's/, $//') ;echo $x
a, b, c
```

Answer (score 9):

One option is to stick with `bash`

```
arr=(a b c)
x=$(IFS=,;printf  "%s" "${arr[*]}")
echo "$x"
a,b,c
```

Alternately

```
arr=(a b c)
printf -v x "%s," "${arr[@]}"
x=${x%,}
echo "$x"
a,b,c
```

With the second option, you can set the separator to `,`(comma followed by space) instead of `,` alone

```
printf -v x "%s, " "${arr[@]}"
x=${x%, }
echo "$x"
a, b, c
```

Comment: Curious: what do you mean be stick with bash? Isn't my approach already bash?

Comment: @Ketan, I meant an approach that does not involve calling out to tools such as `sed`

Answer (score 7):

another useful technique for this is `paste -s`:

```
$ arr=(a b c)
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | paste -sd,
a,b,c
```

(note that the `paste -sd,` here is a very general "turn this set of newline-separated items into a comma-separated list" operation)

Comment: You should be able to avoid the loop with `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | paste -sd,`

Answer (score 3):

Why do you absolutely need to remove the *last* comma?

You're messing things up and then trying to clean up the mess afterward, instead of thinking correctly about the problem in the first place.

There is a solution when you look at the comma as not being located after each item but in front of each item.

```
for i in a b c; do
  u="${u:+$u, }$i"
done
echo $u
```

See [bash parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Result:

```
a, b, c
```

Comment: Appreciate you putting this in here. This is my way of thinking as well and I've used your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ w=(a b c)

$ IFS=, eval 'echo "${w[*]}"'
a,b,c
```

Side note, aren’t we
[reinventing the wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527049)
here?

Answer (score 0):

For the array `a=(1 2 3 4 5)`
If you can modify the array:

```
for (( i=$((${#a[@]}-1)); i-->0; )); do a[i]+=","; done
echo "${a[@]}"
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

`$(( ${#a[@]} - 1 ))` calculates the last-but-one array index and `a[i]+=","` appends a string.
If you want to do it in a function:

```
print_with_commas() {
        while [[ $# -gt 1 ]];do echo -n "$1, ";shift;done;echo "$1"
}
print_with_commas "${a[@]}"
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Pop off each argument to the function, except the last, and echo with `", "` appended with no newline. Then echo the last argument and newline.

Answer (score 0):

check the following script

```
$ cat run.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo example 1
for i in a b c; do echo "${i},"; done
echo example 2
for i in a b c; do echo "${i},"; done|sed '$s/,//'
echo example 3
for i in a b c; do echo "${i}"; done|sed '$!s/$/,/'
echo example 4
SEP=''; for i in a b c; do printf "${SEP}${i}"; SEP=',\n'; done; printf '\n'
echo example 5
STR=''; SEP=''; for i in a b c; do STR="${STR}${SEP}${i}"; SEP=,; done; echo $STR
echo example 6
echo 'a,b,c,'||sed 's/^\(.*\),\(^,\)*$/\1\2/'
echo example 7
echo 'a,b,c,'|sed 's/.\w*$//'
```

It gives the following output

```
$ . run.sh
example 1
a,
b,
c,
example 2
a,
b,
c
example 3
a,
b,
c
example 4
a,
b,
c
example 5
a,b,c
example 6
a,b,c
example 7
a,b,c
```

example 1: our for-loop actually produces lines. The `echo $x` transforms this to a single line.

example 2: You can tell sed to process only the last line

example 3: You can tell sed to process all but the last line

example 4: you can program your for loop that you do some special processing when it is ececuted the first time: dont prepent ',\n' to the line. But in many cases you don't know when it is exectued the last time

example 5: the same as example 4 but you do not produce lines but simply a string

example 6: tell sed to remove the last occurrence of a string in a line

example 7: tell sed to remove the last non whitespace character of  a line